# instagram long lived access token expires after 60 days, enable auto-renew token

Tags: instagram

I have an instagram feed on my website, i created a developers.facebook.com account and made a long lived access token.

However after 60 days I have to log back in and get a new token.

You can renew an access token before it expires.

My question is... can I or should I just create a script that renews the long lived access token server side every time the page is refreshed?

Seems a bit annoying to do that to instagram servers... but what other methods would I have.. i don't know how to run a script every 59 days to get a new token..

Any ideas?

### Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The renewal can be done only on tokens that are older than a day, so running it before that will make no difference. So, with that in mind, I run the refresh code with every call to the API. If it's already refreshed it will be ignored, so practically it will only get refreshed once a day.

Also, it's worth noting that Instagram [limits the number of calls](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting#instagram-graph-api) that you can make, so calling the API with every page refresh doesn't sound like a good idea. To avoid running out of quota, I cache the results and only call the API once per hour.

Here's a [more detailed explanation](https://www.gsarigiannidis.gr/instagram-feed-api-after-june-2020/) of the exact steps that I took. It's been written with WordPress in mind, but for the most part, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Just thinking about the Refreshing Token part. Since you are using WordPress, why don't you create an option in the options table, smt like last_refreshing_token with a datetime value, and decide based on that value if you need to refresh or not the token? I mean, instead of calling it every hour.